# How to save image to server with javascript and python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a Django application, where the user can click a button to start the webcam. Once the webcam is started, the user can save the image onto the Django server. Right now my code can snap a picture with javascript. But I am stuck trying to save the image onto the django server. This is my code so far

**html template**

```
<center>
    <button type="button" name="button" class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg' id='start'>Start Video Capture</button>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-2">
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video><br>
        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#image_model" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark" id="snap">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
</center>

<form action="{% url 'img_submit' %}" method="post" class="image_submit_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Use Image" class="btn btn-primary" id="use_image">
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Get access to the camera!
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true
        }).then(function(stream) {
            //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        });
    }

    $('#snap').fadeIn();

    // Trigger photo take
    document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);

        var url = canvas.toDataURL();

        $("#use_image").click(function() {
            let $form = $(".image_submit_form");
            let form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    url: url,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });

});
```

I am trying to use ajax to send the canvas image to django views where I can save the image to the server with python.

This is my python code so far. I am trying to check if I got the right data to save

**django views**

```
def img_submit(request):
    url = request.POST.get('url')
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

But this returns none. How do I access the image through python and how do I save the image then?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. In your `$.ajax` call, I'd suggest using `method: "POST"`.  Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ , but the default seems to be "GET".  I don't use jQuery often so this is just an inexperienced suggestion from me, anyone who has used it, feel free to comment and I'll update my answer.
2. In your Django code, it looks like you reference the POST variable which is expectable, but I'm not sure how the file is transmitted in your AJAX request, maybe it is sent as a file in which case you will want to check the docs again: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST references another page for files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES (Again, on further consideration I'm not sure this is the right track to try, but after you change your JS code, if the POST variable doesn't have the right stuff, try the FILES variable.)

Finally, I'm not sure if POST is a QueryDict, but the docs seem to point to it, you can list the data to see if you are getting *anything* at all, try adding something like this for img_submit:

```
def img_submit(request):
    url = request.POST.dict()
    return HttpResponse(url)
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply. I am using POST to send data with ajax. please check this line `type: $form.attr('method')`. As for using `request.POST.dict()`, this is the result. `csrfmiddlewaretoken`

Comment: I am not sure, If I am sending the right data with jquery.